# On key combination

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, key, combinations

I am trying to make a little "Feature" on my program , basically what I want it to do is when the user pressed CapsLock Then Do this key combination "Ctrl + Alt + Right" . The command is for changing desktop screens on windows 10. Any suggestions ?

```
Public Class CapsLockIndicator

Public Shared Sub Main()

    If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ist eingeshaltet.")

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ist ausgeshaltet.")
    End If
End Sub 'Main
End Class 'CapsLockIndicator
```

Comment: `what I want it to do is when the user pressed CapsLock Then Do this`, sounds good, ***show us what you have tried and what is not working***. Not showing us an attempt tells us its not that important as you clearly did not show any code in question and or research. What make's you think it's important to us to do it all for you...? Please update question with what you have tried and what is not working as this question may be marked for closing.

Comment: all I have at the moment is this 
Public Class CapsLockIndicator

    Public Shared Sub Main()

        If Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ist eingeshaltet.")

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Caps Lock ist ausgeshaltet.")
        End If
    End Sub 'Main
    

End Class 'CapsLockIndicator

later I call this on the event keypressed to check if the capslock is pressed then i want to execute the key combination

Comment: Thank you for your response, please update your question with this code in question, not a comment. It is hard to track these things in comment's... Thank You.

Comment: sorry codexer , I fixed it :)

Comment: Why do you want to make the caps lock key do something different from what everyone is expecting it to do?

Comment: Have a look at [SendKeys.Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0):

Set the key preview property to true at form level. Within the keyboard events in the form check if the pressed key is Keys.CapsLock

Comment: hey it works now :) but one more question if you don't mind , how do I assign the keys "CTRL + ALT + RIGHT " to be activated after caps lock is pressed ?

Comment: What does your application do when it receives "CTRL + ALT + RIGHT"?